# Can't connect on local DB using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, connection

My connection method:

```
public static SqlConnection con()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder cnnSb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        cnnSb.DataSource = @"(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb";
        cnnSb.AttachDBFilename = @"|DataDirectory|\Database2.mdf";
        cnnSb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        SqlConnection kon = new SqlConnection(cnnSb.ToString());

        return kon;
    }
```

and Database2.mdf is created in **App_Data**

Comment: What error do you receieve?

Comment: What should it return `con` or `kon`?

Comment: shoult return kon

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre don't receive any error, but in Server Explorer shows that is not connected...

Comment: Why you don't merge the connectionString insteat of grouping..

Answer (score 0):

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
 conn.ConnectionString = 
 "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;" + 
 "User Instance=true;" + 
 "Integrated Security=true;" + 
 "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database2.mdf;"
 conn.Open();
```